# Comparison 'is null or not an object'. Bug

Tags: javascript, c++, debugging

I have a large piece of javaScript. It runs for a long time (Days at a time). While testing, Have found that on occasion the error: ***"p[...].name is null or not an object"***

Testing on several different systems but the bug has only occurred on 2 PCs running XP & IE8 (However, the bug occurs once every few days. Can't be certain that the OS/Browser version is causing the crash).

```
function findPUnits(name) {
var i;

for (i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
    if (p[i].name === name) { // <-- BUGS HERE
        if (p[i].units === "hour" || p[i].units === "min" ) {
            return (p[i].value==1) ? p[i].units : p[i].units + "s";
        }
        return p[i].units;
    }
}
return "";}
```

The array "p" is filled from values taken from an XML sheet. The XML sheet is updated by a program running in C++. I have added a check when the values are parsed in (Checks they are not null or undefined, and if they are inserts a blank string instead)... However the error is still occurring.

Comment: Can you post a sample of `p`'s contents? (Preferably a sample that works, and one that causes the error) JavaScript doesn't usually throw a error if you're trying to compare a `undefined` value, though.

Comment: p is full of objects like this: `function P(name, units, value) {
 this.name = name;
 this.units = units;
 this.value = value;

 if (units && units.length) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(",", ".");
 }
}`

Comment: I'm not going to be able to post the entire script I'm afraid. I'm a placement student, Can't share all my companies work. (Also the program is huge and you would need to have the C++ too to run it). I don't want to; But I might have to put some try/catches in.

Comment: @User2: You're not supposed to. You're supposed to post a [testcase](http://sscce.org). The same one you've been debugging with so far.

Comment: Didn't realise that. Thank you. Will take it on-board.